# Currently use MVVM Light Messanger, need to switch to XAML instance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

so currently in order to change a view in my MainWindow I use MVVM Light Messanger to send a message to my MainWindow.xaml.cs, which executes the following:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Messenger.Default.Register<NavigateMessage>(this, (action) => ShowUserControl(action));
            this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }
        private void ShowUserControl(NavigateMessage nm)
        {
            Holder.Content = nm.View;
        }
```

This is the code which sends the NavigateMessage to this Receiver end:

```
var msg = new NavigateMessage { View = View, ViewModelType = ViewModelType, ViewType = ViewType };
Messenger.Default.Send<NavigateMessage>(msg);
```

However i'm adapting some other code to work with this, however I need to set the `Holder` Object's content by binding to an instance of the NavigateMessage object which will be defined and updated within App.xaml

How would I go about doing this? Would I need an additional class which I would create an instance of in the XAML, the class would contain the get,set properties so that anything binded to this instance would get updated?

This is what I currently have:

```
namespace PhotoManagement
{
    public class ViewChange : Common.NotifyUIBase
    {
        private NavigateMessage _v;
        public NavigateMessage V
        {
            get { return _v; }
            set
            {
                if (_v != value)
                {
                    _v = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However getting the following error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'NavigateMessage' is less
>   accessible than property

**NavigateMessage.cs**

```
namespace PhotoManagement
{
    class NavigateMessage
    {
        public Type ViewType { get; set; }
        public Type ViewModelType { get; set; }
        public UserControl View { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
**------------------------------------------------------------------------**

My application is getting an exception when I try to run it now, I have got a feeling that this is due to the way in which i'm adding the Content to my Control:

```
<Controls:AnimatedContentControl Content="{StaticResource CurrentView}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
```

This is the StaticResource

```
<local:ViewChange x:Key="CurrentView" />
```

And below of course is the class which the StaticResource is an instance off

```
namespace PhotoManagement
{
    public class ViewChange : Common.NotifyUIBase
    {
        private NavigateMessage _v;
        public NavigateMessage V
        {
            get { return _v; }
            set
            {
                if (_v != value)
                {
                    _v = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This Instance is then updated like so:

```
var msg = new NavigateMessage { View = View, ViewModelType = ViewModelType, ViewType = ViewType };

//Replace XAML Instance with new View
((ViewChange)Application.Current.Resources["CurrentView"]).V = msg;
```

I believe my `ViewChange` class is created incorrectly, as the Content call will not know to look within the `V` property, how do I fix this? I have attempted

```
{StaticResource CurrentView.V}
```

However this just causes another error.

Comment: This is a completely different question. Only ask one thing at a time. For your other issues, please open a new question and provide more infos. People here can't read your minds, you have to provide the exact error message if someone is to help you without guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot the `public` access modifier on your `NavigateMessage` class. By default, classes are `internal`, hence less accessible than `public`.

This should do the trick

```
public class NavigateMessage
{
    public Type ViewType { get; set; }
    public Type ViewModelType { get; set; }
    public UserControl View { get; set; }
}
```

You got to read the error messages, it tells you already :)

Comment: I saw that, however the tutorial I was following before didn't have it as a public class, so was wondering if there maybe would be some kind of downfall to making it public?